# Scrapy playwright gets stuck on Telnet console listening

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

I am doing a practice project about scraping dynamically loaded content with scrapy-plawright but I managed to hit a wall and cannot figure out what's the issue is. The spider simply refuses to start the crawling process and gets stuck on the "Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023" part.

I set up the project as it is is recommended in the tutorial.

this is how the relevant part of my **settings.py** looks like (I played around other settings too to try to fix it like with `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` and `COOKIES_ENABLED` but no changes)

```
import asyncio
from scrapy.utils.reactor import install_reactor

install_reactor('twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor')
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())


DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}

TWISTED_REACTOR = 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'
```

And this is how the **spider** itself:

```
class roksh_crawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "roksh_crawler"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url="https://www.roksh.com/",
            callback=self.parse,
            meta={
                "playwright": True,
                "playwright_page_methods": [
                    PageMethod("screenshot", path="example.png", full_page=True),
                ],
            },
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        screenshot = response.meta["playwright_page_methods"][0]
        
        # screenshot.result contains the image's bytes
```

I tried to take a screenshot of the page but nothing else works either so I assume this is not the issue.

And here is the the **log** I am getting:

> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.7.1 started (bot: roksh_crawler)
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.1.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.7.0, w3lib 2.0.1, Twisted 21.7.0, Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.1.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022), cryptography 38.0.3,
> Platform Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
> {'BOT_NAME': 'roksh_crawler',
> 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 32,
> 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'roksh.spiders',
> 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
> 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
> 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['roksh.spiders'],
> 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: SelectSelector
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.windows_events._WindowsSelectorEventLoop
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 7aad12ee78cfff92
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
> ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
> 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
> 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
> ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
> ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
> []
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
> 2022-11-24 09:54:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
> 2022-11-24 09:55:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
> 2022-11-24 09:56:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
> 2022-11-24 09:57:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
> 2022-11-24 09:58:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
> 2022-11-24 09:59:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
> 2022-11-24 10:00:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
> 2022-11-24 10:01:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
> 2022-11-24 10:02:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
> 2022-11-24 10:03:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

and this goes on infinitely.

I also tried with different URLs but got the same result so I assume the problem is on my end not on the server's. Plus if I try to run the spider without playwright (so if I take out the `DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS` from the settings) then it works, albeit it only returns the source HTML which is not my desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me.

Just remove or comment out these lines in your `settings.py` file

```
# import asyncio
# from scrapy.utils.reactor import install_reactor

# install_reactor('twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor')
# asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Comment: Sadly I need those because on windows asyncio is a bit wacky, and if I comment those out, I get a `AttributeError: 'PipeTransport' object has no attribute '_output'` error.

reference: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/asyncio.html

Comment: @KrisztiánDobos Trying to use scrapy-playwright on windows is a mistake and will likely just cause headaches....  If you are on windows 10 or 11 you can use wsl  and it will work seemlessly

Comment: Great, this worked, thanks. I knew that getting playwright working with windows is finicky but I didn't know it's nigh impossible :D